# Dynamically created textbox values are not displaying in the dynamic Texbox when i click the button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a TextBox dynamically, and i am getting the value of the textbox when i click the button. But the value entered in the dynamic textbox gets empty when i click the button.

Below is my ASPX Code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Reports.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

</div>

<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
    onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack = "true">
    <asp:ListItem>Text</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Check</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList> 

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="GetTextBoxValue" />   
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**CodeBehind:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Reports
{
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox TB = new TextBox();
        TB.ID = "abc";
        form1.Controls.Add(TB);
        Response.Write(Request.Form["abc"]);
    }

    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        createcontrol();
    }


    protected void createcontrol()
    {
        if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToLower().Trim() == "text")
        {
            TextBox TB = new TextBox();
            TB.ID = "abc";
            form1.Controls.Add(TB);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

TextBoxes save their state by default. `EnableViewState` is true by default.

If you want to retain the text value, you have to add the `TextBox` on the `Init` or `Load` event.

Answer (score 0):

You should get you dynamically created controls, in `Page_PreRender` - event.

Like so:
//get values

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   //....
}
```

but you should use `IsPostBack` in `Page_Load` when you creating you element's.

[this will help](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/73728/ASP-NET-Application-and-Page-Life-Cycle)